# Instagram's new API gives APINotAllowedError while getting follows/followed_by requests

Tags: instagram

With the recent update on Instagram's API, they removed a lot of functionality and introduces new permission scopes with Sandbox mode. actually everything works fine but requesting a sandbox user's follows and followed_by lists are catching `APINotAllowedError`. any thoughts how to achieve that problem ?

Comment: Have u set scope `follower_list` for login ? https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/

Comment: that scope is the first thing did i check. but no hope. they basically remove `{user-id}` parameter in their api documentation for follower_list https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows apperently we only make requests to `GET/users/self/follows`

Comment: Instagram just kill my business with that move. Not cool instagram. not cool.

Comment: i know, i created http://gramfeed.com, lot of functionality will be gone

Comment: i planning to submit my app to review with the old api keys. they're still valid until June 2016. i hope they're accept my request.

Comment: @krisrak  Did you find any solution regarding this ? I have come across with same problem.

Comment: no longer supported, see answer below

Answer (score 0):

The new Instagram API only allows follower/following list access for the logged in user. You need `follower_list` permission.

You cannot access other users' follower/following list anymore, you have to use instagram app or instagram.com

Here is list of API changes from before and June1 changes:
https://www.picodash.com/about/gramfeed-picodash-features